# Laravel: is there a way to organize routes into hierarchical tree

Tags: laravel, routes, authorization

My `user` model has different roles which have `inheritance` relationship between each other, for example: admin is a child of superadmin.

I am trying to drop this relationship on my **routes** in order to organize them and avoid routes like:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin\MultiDispatch', 'middleware' => ['auth.jwt:superadmin|admin']], function () {

 });
```

I moved every role routes into files `Admin.php` & `SuperAdmin.php`
and required the files in `routes.php`:

```
 /*ADMIN ROLES*/
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.jwt:admin']], function () {
    require base_path('routes/roles/Admin.php');
});

/*SUPERADMIN ROLES */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.jwt:superadmin']], function () {
    require base_path('routes/roles/SuperAdmin.php'); 
});
```

and in `superadmin.php` I required `Admin.php` file again as `superadmin` should extend all `admin` routes:

```
 <?php
    require base_path('routes/roles/Admin.php');
```

But it seems that the endpoints that exist in `Admin.php` are only available to `superadmin` access.
is there another way to implement the inheritance concept in routes file except mention superadmin in admin routes?

```
 /*ADMIN ROLES*/
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.jwt:admin,superadmin']], function () {
    require base_path('routes/roles/Admin.php');
 });
```

especially my tree is long and there are so many roles under admin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can totally separate them by creating new route files in `routes` folder then map them.

- Create `admin.php` and `superadmin.php` routes in your `/routes` folder.
- Go to `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`
- *If you want to have separate controllers for them, create separate Namespaces for them:*

```php
    public function map()
    {
        ...
        $this->mapAdminRoutes();
        $this->mapSuperAdminRoutes();
        ...
    }

    protected function mapAdminRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('admin')
            ->middleware(['web', 'auth.jwt:admin'])
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')
            ->name('admin.')
            ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
    }

    protected function mapSuperAdminRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web', 'auth.jwt:superadmin')
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdmin')
            ->name('superadmin.')
            ->group(base_path('routes/superadmin.php'));
    }
```

Check the `namespace`, that means you can put different controllers in different folders, eg. the admin controllers in `App\Http\Controllers\Admin`, so you can create a folder in `app/Http/Controllers` called `Admin`. Then in the controllers you change your namespace to `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;` then `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` to find the BaseController you are extending from.

`prefix`: /{prefix}/your-routes-here
`name`: Naming your route group, eg. `route('superadmin.users.add')`
`namespace`: Where your controllers are
`group`: Where your routes file is

In the route file you can add routes like you would for normal guest/web routes. Just add them one by one or even group them again. But the above will already be grouped by prefix: `/admin or /superadmin`, and named `admin. or superadmin.`, and middleware attached, and in different folders for conveniency.

Type `php artisan route:list` in your console/terminal and see the results!

With the above I always separate my `/admin` or `/dashboard` from `/` (guest) routes. Much cleaner this way! :)

Answer (score 1):

### Middleware Groups

You can group midleware together in a way that I think will suit your needs;

```
Route::middleware(['auth.jwt:admin'])->group(function(){

  // Routes that need admin middleware access go here

  Route::middleware([''auth.jwt:superadmin''])->group(function(){

    // Routes that need admin AND superadmin middleware access go here

  });

});
```

That should allow you to just nest middleware groups inside one another to provide a hierarchical list of routes.